# Ordering of streams while reading data from multiple kafka partitions

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have used flink streaming API in my application where the source of streaming is kafka. My kafka producer will publish data in ascending order of time in different partitions of kafka and consumer will read data from these partitions. However some kafka partitions may be slow due to some operation and produce late results. Is there any way to maintain order in this stream though the data arrive out of order. I have tried BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor but it didn't served the purpose. While digging this problem I came across your documentation (URL: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Time+and+Order+in+Streams) and tried to implement this but it didnt worked. I also tried with Table API order by but it seems you not support orderBy in flink 1.5 version. Please suggest me any workaround for this. I am using below custom watermark generator with parallelism 4.

```
DataStream<Document> streamSource = env
                        .addSource(kafkaConsumer).setParallelism(4);

public class BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<Document> {

    private final long maxOutOfOrderness = 3500; // 3.5 seconds

    private long currentMaxTimestamp;

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(Document event, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        Map timeStamp = (Map) event.get("ts");
        this.currentMaxTimestamp = (long) timeStamp.get("value");
        return currentMaxTimestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        // return the watermark as current highest timestamp minus the out-of-orderness bound
        return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you applied the `keyBy` before `orderByTime`?

Comment: No, I haven't applied keyBy